# Is it possible to extend a class eventhough that same class is an extention of another class?

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, class-diagram

So in this code:

```
Class A extends D {
}

Class B extends A {
}

Class C extends A {
}

Class D extends ... {
}
```

Would it be possible to note A in the place of the dots?
Would it be possible to note B in the place of the dots?
Would it be possible to note C in the place of the dots?

Comment: When class A extends D, class D cannot extend A. This is a circular dependency, it's impossible. Everything that ends up as a circle is not possible.

Comment: Hi, is your question language specific or general? (it seems not to be Java, since `Class` is capitalized whereas java has it lowercase) - If yes, you may add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Class extension ([inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))) can be represented in a class diagram as follows:

[image]

You are perfectly allowed to have multi-level inheritance as this diagram shows. So B could inherit from A that itself inherit from D, and so on.

But you can never have a cycle in the inheritance graph.  So D cannot inherit from one of the classes that directly or indirectly extend it.  In other words, `...` cannnot be A, nor B, nor C.

Depending on your language, you may or not have [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) (in Java for example it is forbidden).  But multiple inheritance (extending at the same time several classes) is not to be confused with multi-level inheritance (your example).